# Mapping AAD Directory Roles permissions to Graph permissions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to programmatically determine which Graph permissions a user is inheriting when it's assigned to a specific AAD Directory role. When you look at a built-in Azure Active Directory role, its permissions are listed in the form of a path. For example, for the `Global Reader` role, the first one is
`microsoft.directory/accessReviews/allProperties/read`, as displayed on the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/?feature.msaljs=false#view/Microsoft_Azure_PIMCommon/UserRolesViewModelMenuBlade/%7E/description/roleObjectId/f2ef992c-3afb-46b9-b7cf-a126ee74c451/roleId/f2ef992c-3afb-46b9-b7cf-a126ee74c451/roleTemplateId/f2ef992c-3afb-46b9-b7cf-a126ee74c451/roleName/Global%20Reader/isRoleCustom%7E/false)

[image: Azure portal screenshot]

or using the `Microsoft.Graph` Powershell module:

```
PS> $roleDef = Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleDefinition -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Global Reader'"
PS> $roleDef.RolePermissions.AllowedResourceActions
microsoft.directory/accessReviews/allProperties/read
microsoft.directory/accessReviews/definitions/allProperties/read
```

However, Graph permissions are usually expressed in this format: `User.Read`, `Directory.ReadWrite.All`. For example, for a user, you can check its delegated and application permissions with:

```
Get-MgUserOauth2PermissionGrant -UserId $userId
Get-MgUserAppRoleAssignment -UserId $userId
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why the difference between AAD Role permissions and Graph permissions ?
2. How can I map AAD Directory Role permissions to Graph permissions ?

Comment: If you ask question on Microsoft Q&A by using the tag "azure-ad-graph-deprecation" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/azure-ad-graph-deprecation.html , right person can answer you question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got confirmation from a Microsoft engineer that it's not possible to map [built-in AAD role permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference) to [Graph permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference).

Azure AD built-in roles will grant access to data that's also possible through Graph permissions, but Graph permissions allow for more granular management of access to data.

With this said, certain endpoints will require you to have both Azure AD built-In roles and Graph permissions.
For example, the "delete user" endpoint requires the logged-in user to have at least the User Administrator role to proceed.